Tracking Page Visits in React using database at backend or API
I have a home page where whenever a user visits, I want to know how many times it has been visited till date. Now I dont required to save the count on local storage but in database or persistent storage.

You can have a useEffect with empty dependency array (implementing the componentOnMount). Then make your api call to the database in the useEffect.
Something like this:
useEffect(() => {
  db.collection("posts")
    .doc(postId)
    .update({
      views: increment,
    });
}, []);

See this answer

Sorry can you provide an example, am using local storage as of now.

Checkout this blog

This is local storage, I want to use persistent storage. So basically i can fetch data from Axios or any API using GET call for current value, then update it when i refresh the page and post the same. Or any approach that you think fits.

I have used an online page visit counter using https://www.hitwebcounter.com/webcounter.php
